# What is oracle equivalent for SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD()

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, db2

I have an existing SQL for scheduling admin task in DB2. It uses call SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD(10 arguments). One of the argument is the input to procedure which will be called by this scheduled task.
Is there any Oracle equivalent for same? with arguments.

For example: help me to convert below DB2 to Oracle:

```
call SYSPROC.ADMIN_TASK_ADD(name, begintime, endtime, maxinvocation, schedule, procedure_schema, procedure_name, 'VALUES(51,500,50)', options, remarks).
```

Here VALUES('51,500,50') is the input to procedure, same need to go in case of Oracle too.

Comment: Search for Oracle Jobs

Comment: Some more keywords for you: DBMS_SCHEDULER, DBMS_JOB (both are Oracle packages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DMBS_SCHEDULER allows you to add a job which will execute a stored procedure

[DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm#ARPLS72300)

Here's an example

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => '"HR"."RUN_PROC_DO_NOTHING"',schedule_name => '"YOUR_SCHEDULER_WINDOW_HERE"',job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE'
    ,job_action => 'HR.DO_NOTHING_COMMENTS',number_of_arguments => 2,enabled => false,auto_drop => false,comments => 'will run procedure do_nothing_comments'
    );

  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(job_name => '"HR"."RUN_PROC_DO_NOTHING"',argument_position => 1,argument_value => '1');

  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(job_name => '"HR"."RUN_PROC_DO_NOTHING"',argument_position => 2,argument_value => '2');

  dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(name => '"HR"."RUN_PROC_DO_NOTHING"',attribute => 'store_output',value => true);

  dbms_scheduler.set_attribute(name => '"HR"."RUN_PROC_DO_NOTHING"',attribute => 'logging_level',value => dbms_scheduler.logging_off);

  dbms_scheduler.enable(name => '"HR"."RUN_PROC_DO_NOTHING"');
END;
```

As you can see, the SCHEDULER package is very verbose. BUT, it's extremely flexible. You can chain jobs together, defined very specific windows, etc.

SQL Developer has a GUI that will allow you to manage these easier than typing them out from scratch if you'd like.

[image]